# C# double linked list - previous and next wont connect

Tags: c#, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

i'm learning a bit about linked list and double linked list.

I tried to build a double linked list with previous and next nodes but when i debbug the program the "pointers" wont connect to each other in the places where they're supposed to. in the end of the run of the program the only reasult that is printed out is the last value i wanted to enter the list which was the ONLY value in the list apperantly.

this is my code, i belive it should be alright exept for the problam where the 'previous' and the 'next' nodes wont connect to each other.

```
Node<T> start;
    Node<T> end;

    public void AddFirst(T dataToAdd)
    {
        Node<T> tmp = new Node<T>(dataToAdd);
        if (start == null)
        {
            start = tmp;
            end = start;
        }
        tmp.next = start.previous;
        end.next = tmp.previous;
        start = tmp;


        if (start.next == null)
        {
            end = start;
        }
    }

    public void AddLast(T dataToAdd)
    {
        Node<T> tmp = new Node<T>(dataToAdd);
        if (start == null)
        {
            AddFirst(dataToAdd);
        }

        tmp.next = start.previous;
        end.next = tmp.previous;
        end = tmp;
    }

    public T RemoveFirst()
    {
        if (start == null) return default(T);

        T saveVal = start.data;
        end.next = start.next.previous;
        start = start.next;
        if (start == null) end = null;

        return saveVal;
    }

    public T RemoveLast()
    {
        if (start == null) return default(T);

        T saveVal = end.data;
        end.previous.next = start.previous;
        end = end.previous;

        if (start == null) end = null;

        return saveVal;
    }


    public void PrintAll()
    {
        Node<T> tmp = start;
        while (tmp != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tmp.data);
            tmp = tmp.next;
        }
    }

    class Node<T>
    {
        public T data;
        public Node<T> next;
        public Node<T> previous;

        //etc

        public Node(T newData)
        {
            data = newData;
            next = null;
            previous = null;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: [Double Linked List C#](https://gist.github.com/yetanotherchris/4960171)

Comment: I think you should try to write some unit-tests for your code and add one part of the code at a time. In particular I question why `end.next = tmp.previous;` is there at all, or at least **at that time**.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Thank you! i'll follow your example and check what i did wrong!

Comment: When you create a new tmp, what is in tmp.previous? *wink* Use the debugger and step through the code when you add new elements to your double-linked list. It will be pretty easy to see what's going on in your code...

Comment: @elgonzo I used the debbuger but i was so fixed about the thought that my code was correct the way it was that i did not see the problam there.  but i understand now and i fixed my code. and its relate to your hint *wink wink. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were few connection problem in almost all the methods. I have modified the same and it is working fine.

```
public class DoubleLinkedList <T>
{
    Node<T> start;
    Node<T> end;

    public void AddFirst(T dataToAdd)
    {
        Node<T> tmp = new Node<T>(dataToAdd);
        if (start == null)
        {
            start = tmp;
            end = start;
            return;
        }
        start.previous = tmp;
        tmp.next = start;
        start = tmp;


        if (start.next == null)
        {
            end = start;
        }
    }

    public void AddLast(T dataToAdd)
    {
        if (start == null)
        {
            AddFirst(dataToAdd);
            return;
        }
        Node<T> tmp = new Node<T>(dataToAdd);
        end.next = tmp;
        tmp.previous = end;
        end = tmp;
    }

    public T RemoveFirst()
    {
        if (start == null) return default(T);

        T saveVal = start.data;
        start = start.next;
        start.previous = null;
        if (start == null) end = null;

        return saveVal;
    }

    public T RemoveLast()
    {
        if (start == null) return default(T);

        T saveVal = end.data;
        end = end.previous;
        end.next = null;
        if (start == null) end = null;

        return saveVal;
    }


    public void PrintAll()
    {
        Node<T> tmp = start;
        while (tmp != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tmp.data.ToString());
            tmp = tmp.next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i fixed my code. i know now where my problam was. i needed to break the connection between the links with more steps  because i have both Next and a Previous.  thank you!

Comment: Great. If it worked for you. Please mark it as Accepted answer and give an upvote. :)